# Копирование файлов между двумя удалёнными компьютерами

Tags: ssh, scp

Есть 2 сервера, к которым можно подключиться по ssh используя один и тот же закрытый ключ. Как настроить передачу файлов между серверами scp или rsync используя эти ключи.

Comment: например (простейший вариант, с передачей файла через ваш компьютер): `$ scp -3 компьютер1:/путь/к/файлу компьютер2:/путь`

Answer (score 0):

если вас устраивает, что весь передаваемый поток информации будет проходить через вашу локальную машину дважды — сначала от компьютера1 к вам, затем от вас к компьютеру2, то можно запустить копирование так:

```
$ scp -3 компьютер1:/откуда/копируем/файл компьютер2:/куда/копируем
```

полезным моментом здесь является то, что компьютер1 и компьютер2 могут даже не иметь прямой связи друг с другом.

---

если между компьютером1 и компьютером2 есть прямая связь, и вы хотели бы передавать поток информации напрямую между ними, то потребуется выполнение дополнительных условий:

1. на локальной машине у вас должен работать *ssh-agent*, которому добавлен упомянутый вами секретный ключ (проверить можно командой `$ ssh-add -l`)
2. у пользователя на компьютере1 в файле `~/.ssh/known_hosts` должен присутствовать публичный ключ компьютера2. он будет добавлен автоматически, если (хотя бы один раз) подключиться к компьютеру1 (опция `-A` — использовать *ssh-agent*):

   ```
   $ ssh -A компьютер1
   ```

   а оттуда — к компьютеру2:

   ```
   $ ssh компьютер2
   ```

теперь в команде копирования надо будет указывать использование *ssh-agent* (у программы *scp* нет короткой опции `-A`, как у программы *ssh*, и надо указывать «длинным образом»):

```
$ scp -o forwardagent=yes компьютер1:/откуда/копируем/файл компьютер2:/куда/копируем
```

---

указывать пользователя можно обычным образом: `пользователь@компьютер`. а вот если используется не стандартный 22-й порт, то адресовать компьютеры можно с помощью url-схемы:

```
$ scp -o forwardagent=yes scp://компьютер1:порт1//откуда/копируем/файл scp://компьютер2:порт2//куда/копируем
```

обратите внимание, что после номера порта надо будет добавить ещё один слэш, иначе путь на компьютере будет считаться относительным, и отсчитываться от домашнего каталога пользователя.